# Using a sub str to search through a vector in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Taken a good look around the site and just can't seem to find the specific answer for what I am looking for. I need to read in a text file which contains a few lines of unimportant text. This is stored in a vector word by word. 
I have another text file with a list of words which I have also stored into a vector.

The task that I am given to do is to go through the first text file and replace the words which are also in the second file with 4 question marks "????".

The problem that has arisen is that some of the words in the first file contain punctuation and when I compare these with the second file of words it does not find it because of this punctuation.

From my research it seems that using a substring would be the best option for removing the punctuation as a problem.

I have no prior experience with using substrings and vectors together and really can't get my head around the code that is needed. Code Below:

```
    infile.open ( "textone.txt" );
infile2.open ( "listofwords.txt" );


vector <string> unfiltered; 
vector <string> abbrevi;
ReadAbbreviations( infile , abbrevi ); 

string words; 
while ( infile2 >> words) 
{
    int index;
    unfiltered.push_back( words ); 
}
for ( int i = 0; i < abbrevi.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < unfiltered.size(); j++)
    {
        if ( abbrevi[i] == unfiltered[j] )
        {
            unfiltered[j] = "????";
        }
    }
for ( int i = 0; i < unfiltered.size(); i++ )
{
    cout << unfiltered[i] << ' ';
}
cout << endl;

infile.close();
infile2.close();
system ( "Pause" );
```

Comment: Have you considered treating punctuation as white-space and just just "space" when reading the files in?  This would eliminate the commas, periods, etcetera.

Comment: Warning: using substrings in your censorship algorithm can be dangerous. See: [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), and "[The Clbuttic Mistake](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Clbuttic-Mistake-.aspx)"

Comment: Maybe you could just discard the punctuation when reading the files with the "bad words".

Comment: I am able to remove the punctuation altogether when I read in the file, but the problem is when I am outputting this to the screen it displays a text file with no punctuation which doesn't really make any sense. Is there a way to push back to punctuation if it is found?

Comment: The most accurate way would be with regular expression replacement and word boundary, but I don't know if you have a regex library available.